# Video processing in Clojure

Tags: clojure, video-processing

Can anyone recommend a good library for video processing in Clojure?

I want to:

1. Extract individual frames
2. Get matrix of RGBA values for a chosen frame.

I need to analyze each frame of the video. I looked into imagez but it only works for images and not videos...any help is appreciated...

Comment: You can use any Java library from Clojure. Might be the best place to start.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/cnuernber/avclj

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into using [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/). You could control ffmpeg [using Babashka](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tmgy57R9HZM) or a [thin wrapper library](https://github.com/luissantos/ffclj).